# What does "template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };" mean, and how is it being used with std::visit?

Tags: c++, templates, std

This snippet of code is taken from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit

```
using var_t = std::variant<int, long, double, std::string>;
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
std::vector<var_t> vec = {10, 15l, 1.5, "hello"};

for (auto& v: vec) {
// 4. another type-matching visitor: a class with 3 overloaded operator()'s
// Note: The `(auto arg)` template operator() will bind to `int` and `long`
//       in this case, but in its absence the `(double arg)` operator()
//       *will also* bind to `int` and `long` because both are implicitly
//       convertible to double. When using this form, care has to be taken
//       that implicit conversions are handled correctly.
    std::visit(overloaded {
        [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
        [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
        [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; }
    }, v);
}
```

Can someone explain what `using Ts::operator()...;` means here?
And in the following, what constructor is this calling? with the 3 lambda functions?

```
overloaded {
        [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
        [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
        [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; }
    }
```

I think the concrete overloaded instance is deriving from all 3 of these function types, and then the visitor is picking the right one to use depending on the type of the variant. Is that right?

I just don't fully understand this example.

Answer (score 5):

It creates a struct template called `overloaded` which inherits from all its template arguments. Next, it pulls all declared `operator()` functions from its base classes into its own scope, so these all take part in overload resolution when a user calls `operator()` on an instance of the `overloaded` struct.

The `...` uses [parameter pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) to perform the same operation for all template arguments.

> And in the following, what constructor is this calling? with the 3 lambda functions?

It’s not a constructor, it’s [aggregate initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). In this case it uses [class template argument deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to deduce the template arguments of `overloaded` and initialise its base class instances. Minus the CTAD, the aggregate initialisation is identical to this case:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C : A, B {};

void f() {
    C c{A{}, B{}};
}
```

In effect you’re creating an instance of the `overloaded` struct template, directly initialise an object for it with the given base class objects, and pass that to `std::visit`. The net effect is as if you had defined a struct with multiple `operator()` overloads (which is the normal way of using `std::visit`).